# Supernatural (TV): Sam in Season 9 [Spoilers]

Tags: supernatural

This question contains spoilers for Season 9 of Supernatual.

It is revealed in episode 9x09, *Holy Terror*, that

> the Angel Gadriel is possessing Sam, instead of Ezekiel. When Dean tries to prevent Gadriel from taking control by using the sigil in the storeroom, Gadriel, who has altered the sigil remains in control, and *acts as Sam*, leading Dean to believe Sam is in control, until he kills Kevin.

So the real question is:

> Has Sam ever been in control, or has Gadriel been acting for the whole season?

Comment: Stay tuned, as they say.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Backtracking several episodes, Ezekiel has been erasing Sam's short-term memory whenever he comes out, so that Sam wouldn't remember the specifics of what happened and Dean could explain it away as "you got knocked out cold", or whatever he comes up with on the spot.

At least, he was up until 9x04, [Slumber Party](http://supernatural.wikia.com/wiki/Slumber_Party).  Dean called Ezekiel out in order to heal Charlie.  Later, I believe in the episode or two following, Sam asks Dean, "Who is Zeke?"

If Ezekiel was in control the whole time, *and* pretending to be Sam, there would have been no reason to do that.  He would have remembered that he was "erasing" Sam's short-term memory.  That event in particular seems to indicate he was actually being weakened by continually having to save Sam, Dean, and now Charlie.  He even made it a point beforehand to say that he could help Charlie or help deal with the witch - but not both.

His later conversation with Metatron seems to bear this out; he fully intended to do what he said to Dean:  Heal Sam and then leave, because he wants to be "good" again.  If he was in control of Sam the whole time, it would have been a bit of a disaster when he finally did leave.